# Im trying to recreate this C# code in java to call my web api make i ASP.NET

Tags: java, c#, asp.net

I have written a Asp.net web APi 2, and i protected it with HMAC authentication, and i can query it with C# with this code

```
class Program
{
    private const string _alg = "HmacSHA256";
    private const string _salt = "hidden";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        RunAsync().Wait();

    }

    private static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calling the back-end API");
        string apiBaseAddress = "http://myapi.com/";
        CustomDelegatingHandler customDelegatingHandler = new CustomDelegatingHandler();

        HttpClient client = HttpClientFactory.Create(customDelegatingHandler);


        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiBaseAddress + "api/students/186");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(responseString);
            Console.WriteLine("HTTP Status: {0}, Reason {1}. Press ENTER to exit", response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to call the API. Http Status: {0}, Reason {1}. Pess ENTER to exit", response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}


public class CustomDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private string APIId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiId"];
    private string APIKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiKey"];

    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken )
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        string requestContentBase64String = string.Empty;
        string requestUri = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.ToLower());
        string reqestHttpMethod = request.Method.Method;

        DateTime epochStart = new DateTime(1970, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        TimeSpan timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - epochStart;
        string requestTimeStamp = Convert.ToUInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();

        string nonce = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");

        if(request.Content != null)
        {
            byte[] content = await request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
            byte[] requestContentHash = md5.ComputeHash(content);
            requestContentBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(requestContentHash);
        }

        string signatureRawData = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}", APIId, reqestHttpMethod, requestUri, requestTimeStamp, nonce, requestContentBase64String);

        var secretKeyByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(APIKey);
        byte[] signature = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signatureRawData);

        using (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(secretKeyByteArray))
        {
            byte[] signatureBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(signature);
            string requestSignatureBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(signatureBytes);

            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("amx", string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}", APIId, requestSignatureBase64String, nonce, requestTimeStamp));
        }
        response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Then I've tried to rewrite it to java  but my webservice return a 401, and i cant figure out where its wrong, any ideas what i could do ?

```
String request = null;
String result = "";
URL url;
String requestContentBase64String = "";
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
try {
    url = new URL("http://mysapi.com");
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

    Date epochStart = new Date(0);

    String requestTimeStamp = "" + ((new Date().getTime() - epochStart.getTime()) / 1000);
    String nonce = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");

    if (request != null) {
        byte[] content = request.getBytes();
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] requestContentHash = md.digest(content);
        requestContentBase64String = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(requestContentHash);
    }
    String signatureRawData = String.format("%s%s%s%s%s%s", ApiId, urlConnection.getRequestMethod(),
            url.toString().toLowerCase(), requestTimeStamp, nonce, requestContentBase64String);

    byte[] secretKeyByteArray = ApiKey.getBytes();
    byte[] signature = signatureRawData.getBytes("UTF-8");
    Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(secretKeyByteArray, "HmacSHA256");
    sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
    byte[] signatureBytes = sha256_HMAC.doFinal(signature);
    String requestSignatureBase64String = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signatureBytes);

    String header = String.format("amx %s:%s:%s:%s", ApiId, requestSignatureBase64String, nonce,
            requestTimeStamp);
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", header);

    InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

    int data = reader.read();
    while (data != -1) {
        char current = (char) data;
        result += current;
        data = reader.read();
    }
    System.out.println(result);

} 
catch (MalformedURLException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (InvalidKeyException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (Exception e) 
{

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You must be missing auth tokens sent to web api. 401 is the error and it has to be something about that. Try making that manual request in Fiddler and see what you missed in the headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Request is null.

Use this code, it is working for me.

```
    String request = null;
    String result = "";
    String ApiId = "4d53bce03ec34c0a911";
    String ApiKey = "A93reRTUJHsCuQSHR+L3GxqOJ";
    String json = "";//"{\"key\":1}";
    json = json + "{Password :'Test@123' }";

    URL url;
    String requestContentBase64String = "";
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        //url = new URL("http://mac3uat.jetprivilege.com/api/m1/v1/");
        url = new URL("http://localhost:43326/api/m1/v1/EnrolAccount/IsPasswordValid");

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        //conn.setRequestMethod("POST");


        Date epochStart = new Date(0);

        //String requestTimeStamp = "" + ((new Date().getTime() - epochStart.getTime()) / 1000);
        String requestTimeStamp = "" + ((new Date().getTime() - epochStart.getTime()) / 1000);
        //String requestTimeStamp = "1487513216";

        String nonce = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");

        if (json != null) {
            byte[] content = json.getBytes();
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            byte[] requestContentHash = md.digest(content);
            requestContentBase64String = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(requestContentHash);
        }
```

Rest of your code is correct.